# How to Include moment-timezone in Angular 2 App

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-directives, angular-moment

I realize, this question is repeated but previous once does not provide apt answer 
moment package was already installed

**1.Installed package**

**npm install moment-timezone --save**

Inside **node_modules** directory

|
|--moment
|--moment-timezone

directories present

**2.**
**Index.html** included script

```
<script src="node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js"></script>
```

**System.config.js**

```
  var map = {
    'moment':             'node_modules/moment',
    'momentzone':         'node_modules/moment-timezone'
  };
  var packages = {
    'moment':             { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'momentzone':         { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
```

**3.Inside component.ts file**

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

export class TimeComponent implements OnInit{
   ngOninit(){
         console.log(moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z").tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z'));

   }
}
```

What should be imported to prevent error
**Property tz does not exist on type 'Moment'**

Comment: Can you import moment from momentzone

Comment: import * as moment from 'moment/moment'_____________________
import moment1 from 'momentzone'                                                                causing error -  Cannot find module 'momentzone'

Comment: Try moment-timezone and if it finds at compile time then update th system.config to have correct name

Comment: If the module only has side-effects, `import 'momentzone';` should suffice.

Comment: Have you installed typings typings install --save moment

Comment: tried - import momet from 'moment-timezone'; error - cannot find module moment-timezone .---------   tried - import 'momentzone'; .. error with tz remains same.------------- tried installing typing but it was alreay installed-------is there need to add defination in typings.json file

Comment: typings for moment-timezone does it exist ?

Comment: What version of typings are you using?

Comment: DId you solve it? I have exactly the same issue, tried all the proposed solutions but nothing works

Comment: Also I can see the `tz` function in my console log but compiler doesn't

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might help.

Run Following command for angular-cli or npm install.

**sudo npm install moment moment-timezone --save** 
**npm install @types/moment @types/moment-timezone --save-dev**

for npm systemjs.config.js

```
   map: {
        'moment': 'npm:moment',
        'moment-timezone': 'npm:moment-timezone/builds'
      }
packages: { 
      'moment': {
          main: './moment.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
       },
      'moment-timezone': {
        main: './moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
}
```

where ever you want to use time-zone in .ts file

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})

export class AppComponent {    
  name = 'Angular';
  jun = moment();// creating obj.
  constructor() {
    this.jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('hh : mm : ss a z');
    console.log(this.jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('hh : mm : ss a z'));
    console.log(moment.tz.names()); // for all time zone.
  }
```

Comment: why sudo for npm install? shouldn't this be avoided?

Answer (score 25):

## Updated for Angular 4

Install `moment-timezone` on your command line:

```
npm i -S moment-timezone
```

Import `moment-timezone` in your component:

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

Use it according to docs:

```
this.time = moment().tz('America/New_York').format('HH:mm:ss z')
```

> 16:20:42 EDT

### docs

[moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

[moment timezone docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

> note: `moment` was intentionally not installed or imported as it is a dependency of `moment-timezone`.

Answer (score 7):

To install **moment-timezone** for Angular in 2018:

1. Install moment.js and moment-timezone

   `npm install moment moment-timezone @types/moment-timezone --save`
2. Import these modules in your .ts file

   `import * as moment from 'moment';
   import 'moment-timezone';`

Github issue: [How to resolve the 'tz' build error.](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/385#issuecomment-357055264)

Answer (score 0):

That error says the Typescript compiler can't find the `.tz(...)` method on `moment`'s type definitions (typings).

All you have to do is install `moment-timezone`'s typings, so it adds `tz` to `moment()`.

(You usually install typings for every lib you are going to use. The thing is that some, such as angular and moment, have their type definition files embedded in the libs' sources themselves, thus freeing you from the need to install *their* typings.)

So, as said, just install `moment-timezone`'s typings:

```bash
# if you have typings version 1.X.X
typings install moment-timezone --save --global

# if you have typings version 0.X.X
typings install moment-timezone --save --ambient
```

And everything should work... if you do one thing more:

Rename your configs from `momentzone` to `moment-timezone` (and add the `.js` files):

```
var map = {
    'moment':                  'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    'moment-timezone':         'node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js'
};
var packages = {
    'moment':                  { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'moment-timezone':         { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

That is needed because the name you use here is the name you are going to use in the `import`. And the name you use in the `import` is the name the typescript compiler will use to find the type definitions. And the typings you installed define a module called `moment-timezone`, not `momentzone`.

After that, use:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone'; // since this module only has side-effects, this is enough
```

That should be all.

---

PS.: In the settings above, your compiler will pick `moment`'s typings from `moment`'s source AND `moment-timezone`'s typings (the `tz` function) from the DefinitelyTyped repository (typings.json).

Sometimes, though, they don't play nice. If that happens to you, you'll have to override `moment`'s typings from source with `moment`'s typings from the DefinitelyTyped repository (typings.json).

In other words do:

```bash
# Only do this if installing moment-timezone alone didn't work...

# if you have typings version 1.X.X
typings install moment moment-timezone --save --global

# if you have typings version 0.X.X
typings install moment moment-timezone --save --ambient
```

Comment: Solved almost all problem but if I include  import 'moment-timezone'; then app won't load with error Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/moment(…) and not included tz will give error. please help

Comment: could you please elaborate what you mean by <>

Comment: typings install moment moment-timezone --save --global --- if i execute this error comes---- typings WARN hastypings Typings for "moment" already exist in "node_modules\momnt\moment.d.ts". You should let TypeScript resolve the packaged typings and uninstall the copy installed by Typings

Comment: <> was just a typo, sorry

Comment: Yes, that is expected. It is telling that `moment` already has typings embedded in it. The thing is that those (embedded) typings are **not** compatible with `moment-timezone`'s typings. So that command installs different typings for `moment`, which overrides the embedded one, and **is** compatible with `moment-timezone`'s typings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120141/discussion-between-sandeep-chikhale-and-acdcjunior).

Comment: @accdcjunior what needs to be done for angular 2.0 latest version. It doesnt have typings.

Comment: Yes this was the solution for me.

Comment: @acdcjunior I imported the moment-timezone like this: `import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';` and it works for me ..... do you know if it has any negative effects?

Comment: @Damsorian I wouldn't know, things have changed a lot since july of last year (no kidding). But, I'd say, if you don't notice any big misfunction, you probably did it right.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and did everything that acdcjunior suggested, but also had to install the typings for moment-node:

```
typings install dt~moment-node --save --global
```

After doing this it worked like a charm.

Comment: solved some part of the problem after adding your typings included but giving error Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/moment(…) if include import 'moment-timezone'; Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use

```
moment(currentTime).tz(timeZone);
```

Here is a working Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-timezone-23