# Unable to chain MomentJS tz onto utc in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

From an API, I'm getting back timestamps in milliseconds, as UTC. I'm using MomentJS in an Angular project (utilizing `angular2-moment`). First I setup:

```
moment.utc(dEvent.date.start)
```

And this displays fine, but of course, in the wrong timezone. I want to specifically display the time in US Eastern, and so found Moment Timezone. According to the docs, I should be able to convert the timezone of a Moment object with the `tz` method, so I tried:

```
moment.utc(dEvent.date.start).tz('America/New_York')
```

VSCode makes no complaint about this, but the Angular compiler says

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_moment__.utc(...).tz is not a function
```

As VSCode doesn't complain, I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Did I screw up Angular, Typescript, or MomentJS?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is a part of Moment Timezone (https://momentjs.com/timezone/), which is a different package. Are you sure you're using that one?

You can add it like this:

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

And import it like this:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

EDIT: I just noticed in your question you said your using angular2-moment, I think you can try angular2-moment-timezone instead.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'm using Moment Timezone :p I didn't add the angular package because I didn't need it's extra functionality, and I did add the `@types` package of it.

Comment: did you try utilizing `angular2-moment-timezone` ? Maybe take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674835/how-to-include-moment-timezone-in-angular-2-app